# How can I force Mac OS X 10.9 to see the ethernet port of my hub (Asix AX88179)?

Tags: network, macos, usb, ethernet

I already downloaded (and installed !) the [latest file](http://www.asix.com.tw/FrootAttach/driver/AX88179_178A_Macintosh_10.9_Driver_v1.0.0_Binary_20131112.zip) from [ASIX.com](http://www.asix.com.tw/products.php?op=pItemdetail&PItemID=131;71;112), which is the latest to this day, but System Information does not list the port as being available when I connect the USB 3 Hub directly to the USB 3 port of my MBP.

[Mike Ohlsen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/5806/mike-ohlsen) wrote [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73140/how-can-i-use-an-asix-ax88179-with-mac-osx-10-8-mountain-lion#comment108532_73140) that when plugging the hub into another USB Hub, and not directly into his Mac, then OS X does detect the ethernet interface and displays the device in the System Information.

I can confirm this. But this is not useful in the long run since this defeats the whole idea of having a SuperSpeed Hub in the first place !

[Leif](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/45776/leif)'s [solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73140/how-can-i-use-an-asix-ax88179-with-mac-osx-10-8-mountain-lion/86418#86418) doesn't work in 10.9. That is :

```
sudo kextunload -b com.asix.driver.ax88179_178a
sudo kextload -b com.asix.driver.ax88179_178a
```

as I get this reply in Terminal :

```
com.asix.driver.ax88179_178a failed to load - (libkern/kext) not found; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
```

And anyway it would be a terrible hassle to have to do this each and every time.

But when my "USB 3 Hub with Ethernet" is connected through a USB 2 Hub, then the kext is loaded (inexplicably for me) :

```
MBP-computer:~ username$ kextstat -l | grep asix
  137    0 0xffffff7f82879000 0x8000     0x8000     com.asix.driver.ax88179-178a (1.0.0) <36 34 7 5 4 3 1>
```

In case you wonder : [image]

Hence my question :

How can I force Mac OS X 10.9 to see the ethernet port of my hub (Asix AX88179) ?

- Since we see that Mac OS X 10.9 can see the port when the hub is connected through another hub
- Since that port indeed works in this configuration, showing that the port is functional (the hardware is effectively working, so is the driver)

Comment: I have a similar problem.  I normally connect my Asix AX88179 via a USB 3.0 hub to my MacBook Air but it is very unstable.  After reading your post, I tried to connect the dongle directly to my Mac and it won't see it.  Point is don't bother connecting via a hub as it quickly disconnects.  Worse, although the network is simply not available, the setting still show green status.

Answer (score 2):

After I posted my comment, I contacted support of my product (ianker.com) and after few email exchange they sent me a replacement dongle claiming that I had a defective unit.

I was skeptical but the replacement actually worked!  MacOSX immediately recognised it when I plugged it in directly into the Mac.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Thought you were the OP.